# A ListView overlaps a SearchView in a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, androidx, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm fixing an app after the AndroidX migration, and I had a very odd bug that my `ListView` was not being loaded on the `onCreate`/`onStart`/`onResume` events:

[A ListView is not displaying any data on OnCreate/OnStart after AndroidX migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233700/a-listview-is-not-displaying-any-data-on-oncreate-onstart-after-androidx-migrati)

By matter of chance, I decided to "simplify" my layout and removed a `LinearLayout` that contained the `ListView`. After this change, the data was loaded properly because it seems `LinearLayout` was somehow blocking the `getView` event. However, after this change, the `SearchView` is being overlapped by the `ListView`, and I don't know how to put them in the right order (first the `SearchView` followed by the `ListView`).

This is how it looks now:

[image: example]

This is my code:

**other_ruins.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/search_container" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstOtherRuins"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_container"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**search_container.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Regarding, the **search_container** I tested also using the `AppBarLayout` and crashed the app; therefore, it's not a solution.

Any idea how can I fix it? And why is this happening? If you know how to fix the previous issue and somehow call the `getView` event on the `onCreate`/`onStart`/`onResume` events is another solution.

Comment: Just didn't notice that you tested with `AppBarLayout` before posting the answer .. can you show the crash report that raised when you used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I needed to wrap my `FrameLayout` with a `AppBarLayout` make it work properly, when I didn´t do it, it duplicates the toolbar creating an strange shadow. This is the final change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Only one of them breaks the app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `FrameLayout` in the `search_container.xml` with `AppBarLayout` as the `AppBarLayout` should wrap the `Toolbar` when you're using the `Toolbar` within the `CoordinatorLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: It's a partial solution but still gave me some guidance. You need to combine both to make it work. Thanks Zain.